# Level won't load in impactjs

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I having trouble loading a level using ImpactJs. When I try to load to a level I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Failed to load resource:  loader.js:91
>   ig.Loader.ig.Class.extend._loadCallback loader.js:91
>   ig.Image.ig.Class.extend.onerror

I have a level called map1 saved in my level folder and the following code to load it:

```
    ig.module( 
    'game.main' 
)
.requires(
    'impact.game',
    'impact.font',

    'game.levels.map1'
)
.defines(function(){

MyGame = ig.Game.extend({



    init: function() {
        // Initialize your game here; bind keys etc.

        this.loadLevel( LevelMap1 );
    },

    update: function() {
        // Update all entities and backgroundMaps
        this.parent();

        // Add your own, additional update code here
    },

    draw: function() {
        // Draw all entities and backgroundMaps
        this.parent();



    }
});


// Start the Game with 60fps, a resolution of 320x240, scaled
// up by a factor of 2
ig.main( '#canvas', MyGame, 60, 960, 960, 1 );

});
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: there is `impact.font` as requires. Is it necessary to add something like `font: new ig.Font( 'media/04b03.font.png' ),` into extend()? Just guessing...

Comment: Check this on [impact forum](http://impactjs.com/forums/help/uncaught-failed-to-load-resource-error). Strange but maybe could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use : https://github.com/phoboslab/impact-splash-loader/blob/master/impact-splash-loader.js

Like this:

```
.requires(
    'impact.game',
    'impact.font',
    'plugins.impact-splash-loader',
    //...
});
```

And

```
ig.main( '#canvas', MyGame, 60, 960, 960, 1 , ig.ImpactSplashLoader );
```

Else perhaps, you are missing an image...